# How to (How do YOU) Deal with Rajasic and Tamasic People?

Tags: vedanta

I am newbie to Advaita Vedanta. I have completed few Upanishads, almost all Hamsa Gita, some chapters of Ashtavakra Gita and now I am studying Bhagavad Gita. - Sorry about this chronology, but this is how I am trying to gain knowledge because I don't have any GURU (except the one sitting in my own heart) and I got to know everything from the internet only.

I am trying to cultivate SATVIC GUNA in almost all aspects of my life. But I am struggling to deal with Rajasic and Tamasic People in my WAKING STATE.

I live in a locality which is full of Rajasic and Tamasic people. Money (Greed), lies, deceit, intoxication, pride etc. - This is what I see on daily basis.

I won't go into details, but sometimes the activities of these people greatly agitates my mind. Sometimes condition arises that if they abuse me, I have to abuse back. I am even ready to give them some blows, if they try to physically assault me FIRST from their side. I always try to ignore them at my best, but these people considers my SILENCE as a weakness.

You can say that the Rajasic/Tamasic GUNAS of these people are activating Tamasic GUNAS inside mine.

I request you to please tell me How to (How do YOU) Deal with Rajasic and Tamasic People? How can I stop my mind from being agitated?

Please give me practical solution. If you think that something is wrong with my way of thinking then please guide me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: May be duplicate of [How can a person with sattva guna live with rajas and tamas people?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40175/647) as well.

Comment: Satsangatve Nihsangatvam - Good company leads to being company-less (alone/spiritual). Just as you cannot 'forget' something, you can only think about something else, it's hard to 'avoid' rajas/tamas people - just associate with satvik people more, and the rest will automatically fall off.

Comment: @SeverusSnape Thanks for the link. I am new here so I am slowly trying to learn how this whole system works.

Comment: @ram - Thanks for your comment. I will try to find some place where I can get company of SATVIC people and do satsang.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Thanks for the links. I need to include Pranayama, Yoga and Meditation seriously into my learning process because it's almost impossible to avoid RAJASIC and TAMASIC people and their stupid activities

Comment: @VedantaNewBie No problem, for general discussion on Hiduism, you may join this chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism